Fedora Linux VM on Windows 10 HyperV host behind a network proxy cannot access internet
I posted this question over in the Server Fault boards but haven't had any response on it, hoping to get some information by posting it over here.
I'm setting up a Fedora VM using HyperV on a Windows 10 machine. I've got it installed, the VM boots up just fine but I am not able to connect to the internet from the VM via the host computer.
Here's the setup:
Host Machine:
Windows 10 enterprise 22H2
OS Build: 19045.5011
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0
HyperV Manager: v10.0.19041.1
The host is on a company network behind a proxy.
VM Details:
Fedora Workstation
version 40 (workstation edition)
platform_id: platform:f40
When configuring the network adapter for the VM I followed this set of instructions (I know this is meant for using Hyper-V to set up a virtual Windows machine and not a Linux one but I figured if I followed the same principals it would work. Plus, it's the only thing I could really find that is close to my situation).
After following these instructions I have the Internal Virtual Switch created, the Fedora VM running in Hyper-V is set up with that switch, the host machine has a NetIPAddress on the new NAT network and I can ping the host from the VM and vice versa. However, I am not able to access the internet from the Fedora VM. Opening a browser (Firefox) in Fedora and trying to browse to the internet produces an error in the browser saying "We're having trouble finding that site".
In troubleshooting the connectivity of both the Fedora HyperV VM and the host windows computer, here's a summation of what I've found:

From inside the Fedora VM I can ping the host IP Address I set up for the new NAT network using the IP Address
From inside the Fedora VM, using the respective IP Addresses I can ping the DNS Server, the proxy server and the default gateway that the host computer is pointing to. I can also ping another computer on the network the host computer is on. But I can't ping any of these using the URLs for these devices.
From inside the Fedora VM I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or https://www.google.com/
From inside the Fedora VM I cannot browse to the internet using a web browser.
From the host Windows machine I can ping the Fedora VM IP Address on the NAT network I created to connect the VM and the host.
From the host Windows machine I can ping the DNS Server, the proxy server, the default gateway and another computer on the network using both their IP Addresses/URLs.
From the host Windows machine I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or https://www.google.com/
From the host Windows machine I can browse to the internet using a web browser

I know that it is possible for me to have a Linux VM set up on the host computer on this specific network and have it be able to browse to the internet because I've been able to get one set up using Oracle Virtual Box, but I can't browse to the internet using a Linux VM set up using HyperV (which in my case I need to use HyperV instead of Oracle Virtual Box). I don't think there's something different between HyperV and Oracle VB that would prevent being able to browse to the internet from the VM in HyperV but allow internet access from Oracle VB, but I guess it could be possible.
I don't know if it's having trouble because the host computer is on a work network and as such is behind a proxy or if there's something I don't have correctly configured in the Fedora VM. From everything I've read about NAT networks with VMs like this, packets should be routed from the VM to the default gateway (in this case the IP Address I set up for my host machine on the NAT Network) and then the packets should go out from the host machine.
Here's the output of ipconfig /all on my host machine, the details of the new virtual switch in the red box.

And here's the output of ifconfig on the Fedora VM:

Here's the output of pinging public servers by name and IP address from the host Windows machine

Here's the output of the Profile 1.nmconnection file on the Fedora HyperV VM

I'm new to Linux configuration and have exhausted all of my knowledge I can bring to the table in trying to troubleshoot this issue. It seems to me that the issue is that the Linux VM inside HyperV isn't able to resolve URLs, and I've tried to research routing for Linux machines as well as VMs but haven't come across anything that I can understand that would apply to this situation, but that doesn't mean there isn't something out there. There probably is, either I didn't find it or I did find it but didn't understand it. If anyone would help me figure out what I need to do to be able to access the internet from this Fedora VM running in Hyper-V on my Windows 10 host machine I will greatly appreciate it.

Can you add the content of Fedora's /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection?

Thank you for posting the .nmconnection file.  What happens if the dns setting is changed to one of the public DNS servers, for example 8.8.8.8?

Can you `ping by address to a local system (outside your HyperV instance)? Assuming you can do this from normal Windows clients, can you ping a local machine (also outside your HyperV instance) by name? The intention here is to avoid using the proxy and to confirm that basic networking is operational. Without this step you can have no idea where to start looking

I get the same result, an error message in Firefox saying "Hmm. We're having trouble finding that site." Something to note: the more I get into this the more I think it has something to do with my host being behind a proxy because it's on a work network. I can't ping 8.8.8.8 from either the VM nor the host. I can ping the DNS that my host is pointed to just fine (that DNS is what I am using, I blurred it out for security because I don't know if it's public facing or not).

@ChrisDavies I can ping servers on the network the host is connected to by IP address, but not by name. I can't ping any public site by name nor IP. I really think it has something to do with my host being behind a proxy because it's on a work network, seeing as neither IP nor name can be resolved if the site is on a public network.

@ChrisDavies I updated my post with a screenshot of the output when I try to ping Google by name as well as IP.

You're showing screenshots from a Windows powershell. That suggests it's on the HyperV, in which case there's little point trying to get the VMs to work until you've got the underlying system sorted

I’m voting to close this question because not even the underlying Windows HyperV hypervisor is able to access the network properly. You need to fix that first

@ChrisDavies correct, it is on HyperV, that's why I included HyperV in the name for this question as well as the "Windows" tag. The host system is just fine, I can browse to the internet with it no problem. Also, I know that a VM can browse the internet from this network because I've done it before with Oracle Virtual Box. I'm specifically trying to get that same setup working with HyperV but am having issues trying to figure out what needs to be done to get it to work, hence why I asked the question. Like I said before, I can ping the network DNS with both the host and VM.

If the networking issue is with the guest then please provide diagnostics as requested from that guest. As requested earlier please don't ping from or to the hyperv inference as that doesn't prove any network connectivity.

@ChrisDavies Sorry, I was confused with what was being asked for. I believe this is what you were looking for: from the Fedora VM I can ping the host IP, the network DNS server as well as a computer on the network by IP address, I can't ping using the names. From the host, I can ping the Fedora VM, the DNS server and a network computer both via IP Address as well as name. I cannot ping any public server (IE: 8.8.8.8 or google.com) via name or IP Address from my host machine nor from the Fedora VM but I can browse to the internet from the host computer via web browser.

Please put updates in your question. Make it easy for people to read and understand your question by amending it to incorporate the new information rather than just dropping "Edit: new stuff..." at the end. Help us to help you

@ChrisDavies sorry once again, I thought adding EDITs was the preferred convention. I made updates to my original question that works in all of the things I originally had in the EDITs I was making. Thank you so much for being patient with all this, please don't give up on me

"From the host Windows machine I cannot ping 8.8.8.8 or https://www.google.com/" - the ping command doesn't understand URLs. If DNS were working you would usually be able to ping by name, for example ping www.google.com but never ping Https://www.google.com

Now, because you can't ping outside your company network from your Windows machine you're not going to be able to do that from Fedora. So scratch that test entirely

"From the host Windows machine I can browse to the internet using a web browser" - so in principle you should be able to do that from your Fedora machine. Look at the proxy settings in Windows and replicate those into Fedora

@ChrisDavies SUCCESS!!!! The final issue was that I didn't have the proxy settings enabled in my Fedora VM. I had configured them previously but disabled them because after setting them up I couldn't connect, but that was because there were other issues I was working through at that time. After working through all of my other issues and then re-enabling the proxy settings I am now able to browse to the internet from my Fedora VM within HyperV. Thank you so much for all of the help with this, I truly appreciate it!
